# Python index change in the list

Tags: python, list, numbers, return, swap

```py
# write a function that accepts a list and the indexes of two elements in the list,
# and swaps that two elements of the list, and return the swapped list. 
# for example, if the arguments of the function are [23,65,19,90]m index1 = 1, and index2 = 3,
# then it will return [23,90,19,65].


# Swap function

def swapLst(newLst):
    size = len(newLst)
     
    # Swapping
    temp = newLst[0]
    newLst[0] = newLst[size - 1]
    newLst[size - 1] = temp
     
    return newLst
     
newLst = [23,65,19,90]
print(swapLst(newLst))
```

Hello, My question: How can I change my code  to change the any index in the list. My program only changes first and last index, I needed help with that. Thank you!

Comment: The question is entirely clear. They have given an example as well. Try thinking on your own first!

Answer (score 1):

You can swap variables in python using `a, b = b, a`, so you can swap list elements with their indexes:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5] 

def swap(l, i, j):
    l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]
    return l
print(swap(a, 0, 1))
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do so, you need to accept the other integers as arguments as well.
And swapping is easier as `a, b = b, a`
Code:

```
def swapLst(newlst, in1, in2): 
    newlst[in1], newlst[in2] = newlst[in2], newlst[in1]
    return newlst
 
newLst = [23,65,19,90] 
print(swapLst(newLst, 1, 3))
```

Output:

```
[23, 90, 19, 65]
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer!  It should  let me change any index in the list, for example: I want to change index 0 and 2 [23, 90, 19, 65] - [19, 90, 23,65] or I want to change  index 1 and 3 [23, 90, 19, 65] - [23, 65, 19 90]

Answer (score 1):

you can modify the swapLst function to swap the elements at any given indices:

```
def swapLst(lst, index1, index2):
    # Check if indices are valid
    if index1 >= len(lst) or index2 >= len(lst):
        print("Invalid index")
        return lst
    
    # Swapping
    temp = lst[index1]
    lst[index1] = lst[index2]
    lst[index2] = temp
     
    return lst

# Example usage
lst = [23,65,19,90]
new_lst = swapLst(lst, 1, 3)
print(new_lst)   # Output: [23, 90, 19, 65]
```